# C# Windows Forms(Non-SQL): Populate text box on new form with an integer +1 above the highest number currently in a DataGridView row

Tags: c#, winforms

I've working on a C# Forms application, the MainScreen contains a DataGridView in which the first row is an auto-generated incremented number. When manually coding data into the DataGridView, I'm able to set this ID field with the incremented number.

What I'm trying to do now is create an "Add" form, I need the first text box to be populated with the next incremented number when it opens.

What is the simplest way to know what the current last number used in the DataGridView is?

For example, if I have 2 rows, obviously the new "Add" row would have an ID of 3, but how can I code the Text box to dynamically grab that information and increment +1 each time the form is opened?

Edit:
To provide more context, I will have a button for Add, and a button for Modify. The modify button will not open the Modify form unless a row is selected. Here is my code to populate the text box on the modify form, based on the selected row:

```
ModPartIDBox.Text = Inventory.AllParts[Inventory.CurrentIdxPrt].PartID.ToString();
```

The "Add" form obviously doesn't check and doesn't care if a row is selected, so I can't lean on just calling that already filled field, so I just need a way to grab highest number.

Comment: Well… if the code is… _“manually coding data into the DataGridView, I'm able to set this ID field with the incremented number”_ … then couldn’t you just keep track of this “incremented” value? Or as you say… _”if I have 2 rows, obviously the new "Add" row would have an ID of 3”_ … so if there are X rows in the grid, then would not the next “incremented” value be X + 1?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of all objects that you are going to store in your DataGridView so you can access their data later on, such as:

`var items = new List<MyObject> {}`

Where MyObject looks a little something like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int PartId { get; set; }
}
```

and then when you need to pull the highest number, you can use a LINQ expression:

```
int highestNumber = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.PartId).First().PartId;
```

Comment: I've got to be missing something here, or this project is intentionally different for the sake of being difficult. I have attempted everything I can think of or find online to make your solution and others work and I'm genuinely lost. Sorry to waste your time. :(

Comment: @ajrenfro You're not wasting anyone's time. We're here to help :)

Have a foreach loop that adds every item to your DataGrid, but before it adds it to the DataGrid, add the object into a List (with my above example). If you're wanting to pull up all this information when you click on one of the items in the DataGrid, on the OnClick method of your DataGrid, get the current index of the item you clicked, and then throw that index into the List you created earlier of all the objects. objectsList[0] will return the object used to populate DataGridItem[0]